# accessing local host from another computer

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns

This is the first time I am trying to host at IAAS level. I have installed Win 8 on the VM and installed XAMP. I can access local host on the same VM. But how do I access the local host from another computer. I do have the DNS name for the VM i have set up, but I am not able to access the local host on the VM from an external computer in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost can't be reached from another station. Talking about localhost makes only sense when you try to reach the machine you are currently working on.

Example:
I am Peter - I am talking to ME (= localhost)
You are Bill - You are talking to YOU (= localhost)

Always when I talk to localhost I am talking to myself. If I want to talk to you so I have to talk to Bill.

Comment: Thank you. But I cant even ping to the VM using the DNS name or the IP address.

Comment: Most likely you 1) don't have connected the networks correctly or 2) the firewall is blocking all accesses

Comment: I have turned off the firewall of VM, doesn't work. But I cannot even ping to the same VM using the DNS name provided by the Service provider. I am trying to ping to the VM from the same.

Comment: Also, I see two ip addresses, one that I get using IPconfig and the other shown by google as my IP address. Why is there a difference?

Comment: Please ask a new question in the forum. Describe the configuration you have, what you have tried and what you wanna reach.